# Wrap mesh around objects

Tags: shrinkwrap

[image]

How can i make it so i wrap this object all around the rocks like a tape? I have some ugly results with my own shrinkwraps modifier settings..

File > https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zkUsM3kmfe0-8_uYt7SUQyAT4Yl6w1rG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the initial shape of your tape must go around the rocks if you want it to be projected all around

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is not what you want...but maybe you like it ;)

You could use a pure shader solution...with these nodes it looks like this:

[image]

my shrinkwrap try looks like this...but it is far from being perfect:

[image]

my modifiers:

[image]

[image]

to bend your strap i subdivided it a few times:

[image]